# Make a CSV file Downloadable

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I use the below code. But the file created in tmp is not downloading .

```
 $error = fopen(/tmp/error.csv);
     $write[] = "hello";
     $dest_file_path="/tmp/error.csv";
        $dest_file_name="error.csv";
        if(!empty($write))
        {
            $flag = FALSE;
            fputcsv($error,$write,";");
            fclose($error);
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
            header("Content-length: ".filesize($dest_file_path));
            header('Content-Type: text/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$dest_file_name.'"');
            readfile($dest_file_path);
        }
```

Comment: Did you give permission?

Comment: yes . It already has 777 permissions .

Comment: Please don't edit/overwrite your question with my answer without marking it as an edit. I stand at getting downvoting because of it. I'm doing a rollback. You can make an edit after and mark it as an edit with your original post left intact. If something doesn't work in my answer, ask me.

Comment: I have tested my answer below which successfully wrote to the file and downloaded it. Again, add error reporting to your code to see what possible errors you may be getting. I never post answers that I haven't tested myself.

Comment: The error  is "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by"

Comment: Is there anything else above your existing code? Some HTML, other? Sessions, cookie? If so, you can have this as your very first line `<?php ob_start(); ?>` then the rest of your code `<?php $error = fopen('/tmp/error.csv', 'w'); // etc. ?>`. Sometimes that works. You may also have a byte order mark, or a space before your opening `<?php` tag.

Comment: yes having code above. But the mentioned cases were not there. NO spave before <?php . included ob_start();

Comment: It's still not working? Have you checked for a BOM/byte order mark?

Comment: The encodeing is UTF-8.

Comment: Get a copy of Notepad++ http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ then under the "Encoding" menu, look at what the checkmark shows for the file. See if it says "without BOM" or not. If it is not "without", then under the same menu, do "convert to UTF-8 without BOM" then save the file.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is as per [**your original post**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26750433/1) without marking [**your edited post**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26750433/2) as an "**edit**".

---

The problem is that [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) requires 2 parameters.

As per the manual:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("c:\\folder\\resource.txt", "r");
?>
```

So this line:

```
$error = fopen(/tmp/error.csv);
```

should read as (which is missing quotes and since you want to write to the file, `w`)

```
$error = fopen('/tmp/error.csv', 'w');
```

You may need to adjust your path, something to the effect of:

```
$error = fopen('/var/user/you/tmp/error.csv', 'w');
```

or

```
$error = fopen('/var/user/you/public_html/tmp/error.csv', 'w');
```

If you had error reporting on, it would have signaled something similar to this:

> Warning: fopen() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /path/to/file.php on line x

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

More examples from the manual:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("/home/rasmus/file.txt", "r");
$handle = fopen("/home/rasmus/file.gif", "wb");
$handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/", "r");
$handle = fopen("ftp://user:password@example.com/somefile.txt", "w");
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3'));

// fetch the data
mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database');
$rows = mysql_query('SELECT field1,field2,field3 FROM table');

// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
```

taken from this link http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/creating-downloadable-csv-files/